# Mongodb aggregate $push with $cond and $each

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use `$cond` to conditionally `$push` multiple integers onto a numbers array during an aggregate `$group` without any success. Here is my code:

```
Item.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          numbers: {
            $push: {
              $cond: { 
                if: { $gt: [ "$price.percent", 70 ] }, 
                then: { $each: [10,25,50,70] },
                else: null,
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  )
  ...
```

Is Mongo DB just not set up for this right now, or am I looking at this all wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try it without `$each` as below

```
Item.aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          numbers: {
            $push: {
              $cond: { 
                if: { $gt: [ "$price.percent", 70 ] }, 
                then: [10,25,50,70] ,
                else: null,
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }]);
```

Comment: Hi @zangw, thanks for the response! That is what I ended up doing, but then I had to do $unwind twice to unravel my array of arrays. Is that the only way to conditionally push multiple items to an array?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Oh well that works too. THanks! I'll mark you as correct

Answer (score 5):

Provided answers will work but they'll add `null` to the array whenever `else` block gets executed & at the end you need to filter out the `null` values from the actual array (`numbers`) which is an additional step to do!

You can use [$$REMOVE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields) to conditionally exclude fields in MongoDB's `$project`.

```
Item.aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            numbers: { $push: { $cond: [{ $gt: ["$price.percent", 70] }, [10, 25, 50, 70], '$$REMOVE'] } } // With $$REMOVE nothing happens on else
        }
    }]);
```

**REF:** [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Item.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          numbers: {
            $push: {
              $each: { 
                $cond: { 
                  if: { $gt: [ "$price.percent", 70 ] }, 
                  then: [10,25,50,70],
                  else: null
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  )
```